# Can I sell software with in-app purchases via the Mac App Store?

Tags: mac-appstore

I created an OS X software with in app purchases. Can I publish this in the Mac App Store ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering there are million of apps that have In App Purchases (IAPs) then yes.

Comment: Can you give an example of a *Mac App Store* (not an OS X app store) app that has IAP?

Comment: Yes, [OmniFocus for Mac](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/omnifocus-2/id867299399?mt=12) offers in-app purchases.

Comment: Err, wait. Ian, what are you asking? What is the distinction between the "Mac App Store" and the "OS X App Store"? I've never heard the latter term used, but would assume it meant the MAS. :P

Comment: Also 'should I sleep' has IAPs